# Static Library Loading

Tags: unix, static, libraries

I have created a program using a number of statically linked libraries. My question is, are these libraries required to be present when running the executable? It seems that the libraries are accessed as the program will not run if the libraries are not present and their path not included in the LIBPATH environment variable. I had the impression that since they were statically linked they would not be required at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

No, static linking means they are included in the binary you build (and so they are "loaded" when you compile and link, if you will).